# Python debug: How to step into another python scripts?

Tags: python, debugging

I have a python script that runs well. It invokes another scripts like this:

```
  os.system('python creep.py '+ str(time)+' ' +str(date) +' '+name_sample)
```

How can I step into the script "creep.py" when I debug it with pdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. That script is running in a separate process. `pdb` doesn't have any special capability to recognize executables as Python interpreters and "attach" to scripts they may be running.

You shouldn't be shelling out to run another script though... better to just import it and call its methods directly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with kindall that it is a good idea to try importing the other script and calling its methods directly. This will hopefully get rid of your problem, and also it will be easier to trace errors while debugging in the future.