# pdb break point is not stoping at subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, pdb

In **main.py** file I am calling **functionality.py** by using os.popen   and added breakpoint inside **functionality.py**. In this case pdb is not stoping at breakpoint in **functionality.py**.

`main.py`

```
import os
import subprocess


def main():
    print("Main is called")
    breakpoint()
    value = subprocess.Popen(["python", "functionality.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    print("value = ", value)


main()
```

`functionality.py`

```
def functionality():
    breakpoint()
    print("Feature function called")
    return 10
```

So  whats the change I have to make to stop pdb at **functionality.py** file ?

**EDIT:**

[Python debug: How to step into another python scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069885/python-debug-how-to-step-into-another-python-scripts). This tells me that we cant do it using pdb . But is there any other way or debugger that solves my problem ?

Comment: I see multiple breakpoints here; one in `main.py` and one in `functionality.py`. What happens when you run your code?

Comment: It stops at main.py but not in functionality.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python debug: How to step into another python scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069885/python-debug-how-to-step-into-another-python-scripts)

Comment: Is there any other way I can get inside ```functionality.py```  debug mode in this case ?